# How to align row to bottom in a nested column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfGq3.png)

Im having trouble placing two smaller images next to one larger image using Bootstrap 4. However, I cannot seem to align one of the smaller images to bottom such that it is aligned as the bigger image.

The grid should be responsive as well as the image text.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <img src="../assets/img/Iot.png" class="img-fluid">
                                <div class="carousel-caption text-justify" style="bottom: 0px;left: 10%;">
                                        <h1 style="color:white !important">IoT</h1>
                                        <p style="color:white !important">In the forefront of emerging technologies,
                                            Internet of Things (IoT) applications are some of the most challenging and
                                            innovative solutions to work with today... READ MORE</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <img src="../assets/img/fintech.png" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption text-justify" style="bottom: 0px;left: 10%;">
                                                <h1 style="color:white !important">FinTech</h1>
                                                <p style="color:white !important">The growth in digital banking is showing no
                                                    signs of slowing down. Convenience, speed and security aren’t just extra
                                                    benefits in consumers minds anymore... READ MORE</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <img src="../assets/img/smartapps.png" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption text-justify" style="bottom: 0px;left: 10%;">
                                                <h1 style="color:white !important">SmartApps</h1>
                                                <p style="color:white !important">With people using their smartphones more and
                                                    more, they are now
                                                    demanding solutions that can help them complete their task event on the go…
                                                    READ MORE</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you please add image of what you are exopecting

Comment: I edited the post, please check it

Comment: thank you, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `height` and `width` to each image

```css
.big img{
height: calc(500px + 1.5em);
}

.small img{
  height:250px;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 big">
                                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                <div class="carousel-caption text-justify" style="bottom: 0px;left: 10%;">
                                        <h1 style="color:white !important">IoT</h1>
                                        <p style="color:white !important">In the forefront of emerging technologies,
                                            Internet of Things (IoT) applications are some of the most challenging and
                                            innovative solutions to work with today... READ MORE</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row small">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption text-justify" style="bottom: 0px;left: 10%;">
                                                <h1 style="color:white !important">FinTech</h1>
                                                <p style="color:white !important">The growth in digital banking is showing no
                                                    signs of slowing down. Convenience, speed and security aren’t just extra
                                                    benefits in consumers minds anymore... READ MORE</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row mt-4 small">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption text-justify" style="bottom: 0px;left: 10%;">
                                                <h1 style="color:white !important">SmartApps</h1>
                                                <p style="color:white !important">With people using their smartphones more and
                                                    more, they are now
                                                    demanding solutions that can help them complete their task event on the go…
                                                    READ MORE</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```